A problem in storage state and dependency features in Playwright
As a learner of playwright, I have a challenge with "dependency"  and "storage state" features in playwright. I have two products that seems the login process is different on them. In product A, when we login on a specific tab of browser, the authentication data is just valid for the current tab. If I open a new one I have to login again.
On the other side in Product B, when we login on a tab of a browser, the authentication data is valid for all of the tabs on the specific browser.
Now I want to write different scenarios with playwright and I used the storagestate() and dependency features for doing just one time login and using the user.json file for rest of the scenarios.
My problem here is that this approach works for product B but it doesn't work for product A. The reason is that the browser will be closed at the end of the login scenario and when we open a new tab of browser for the next scenario, the product A open the login page again.
I think I need to keep more info on storage state such as localstorage and cookies but I don't know these info already save in storagestate or I need to add more line for saving more details on it. If it is the second option how can I do that ? how can I save session storage fully with using dependency feature ?
I used the storagestate and dependency features same as what is describe in playwright page 

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Looks like storageState Data/Authentication data is store in IndexDB also in Product A Login, so only the tests are not getting authenticated.  You can move those respective tokens/cookies to Browser local storage then this issue will be fixed.
